# Select2-rails 4.0.3 cannot trigger ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, select2-rails

I can success to get an array result by having following code in script

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "/search",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        query: "test",
      },
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
```

but when I try to use ajax in select2-rails

```
$(".select2").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/search",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    delay: 250,
    data: { query: "test" },
    processResults: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      return {
        results: data.results,
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  theme: "bootstrap",
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  multiple: true,
  templateResult: TemplateResult,
  templateSelection: TemplateSelection,
  placeholder: "Type to search",
});
```

**It seems like it cannot make ajax GET request inside select2 because console is always nothing.**

The select2 should not have problem at assets included part since it works like charm when I used pre-defined data

```
var data = [{ id: 0, name: 0 }, { id: 1, name: 1 }];

$(".select2").select2({
  data: data,
  theme: "bootstrap",
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  multiple: true,
  templateResult: TemplateResult,
  templateSelection: TemplateSelection,
});
```

Comment: Add Jquery's ajax error to check for server errors.

Comment: @dan-klasson ,I add the 
    ```$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
      console.log(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError);
    });```

before the $(".select2").select2 event but it never be triggered also. Cant log any ajax error.

Comment: I've never used `ajaxError`. What does your rails server console say?

Comment: rails server console no error and just loaded necessary js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the script, it should trigger the select event when document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... }
```

and declare the monitoring element using select element like following

```
<select class="select2" multiple="multiple" name="search[item_ids][]"
 id="search_item_ids" />
```

but not using hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :item_ids, multiple: "multiple", class: "select2" %>
```