# Rails Select2 Gem using Ajax not displaying data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I need help in select2 gem ajax request, where i can't display any data.
I can't get also any response from the console and server.
I was using this as a reference or guide [jQuery Select2 not displaying Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800529/jquery-select2-not-displaying-data) and [Select2-rails 4.0.3 cannot trigger ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550998/select2-rails-4-0-3-cannot-trigger-ajax). Thank you for any help.

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :advertiser do
  resources :service_providers do
    collection do
      get :cities # return /advertiser/service_providers/cities
    end
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
def cities
  cities = Model.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%").map{ |rec| { :id => rec.id, :text => rec.name }}
  render json: cities
end
```

**result from controller**

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Result 1"},{"id":2,"text":"Result 2"},{"id":3,"text":"Result 3"}]
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#service_provider_city_name").select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "/advertiser/service_providers/cities",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term

          };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {

          return {
            results: data
          };
        },
        cache: true
      }

    });

  });
```

please help me ...

Comment: Maybe 

return {
            results: data.results
          };

Comment: @snake still didnt get any data

Comment: does it trigger processResult function? Add there console.log("processResults:" + data)

Comment: @snake, hello thank you for helping me.. I really appriciate :). Back to issue, i tried this inside processResult function "console.log("processResults:" + data) " it didn't give any response in console.

Comment: Does select2 send request to controller?

Comment: @snake it didnt send request to controller also.. maybe i have an error in my controller? i tried some dummy data or array to be pass in data attrib in select2 it works perfectly but once i use ajax request it didn't send any request and response.

Comment: Check your js console in brower. Make sure `$(document).ready(function()` is called. Put there `console.log("ready is called")`